# Packet sniffing getting only private IP addresses with raw socket

Tags: python, networking, packet, packet-sniffers, raw-sockets

I'm trying to code a packet sniffer that detects the different websites that are visited by the devices connected to my wifi. The problem is that I'm only getting private IPs, here are the counted IPs I get from a 1 hour sniffing :

```
IPS                  Number_Of_Values
224.0.0.251          1068
192.168.1.255        387
255.255.255.255      32
224.0.0.22           28
224.0.0.1            28
192.168.1.111        6
192.168.1.115        5
224.0.1.187          2
```

Here is a part of the sniffer, **ethernet_frame** is getting mac addresses and proto, **ipv4_packet** unpacks the IP header and gets the IPs (source and target) and finally **get_packets** proceeds to the different unpackings:

```
def ethernet_frame(data):
    dest_mac, src_mac, proto = struct.unpack('! 6s 6s H', data[:14])
    return get_mac_addr(dest_mac), get_mac_addr(src_mac), socket.htons(proto), data[14:]

def ipv4_packet(data):
    version_header_length = data[0]
    version = version_header_length >> 4
    header_length = (version_header_length & 15) * 4
    ttl, proto, src, target = struct.unpack('! 8x B B 2x 4s 4s', data[:20])
    return version, header_length, ttl, proto, ipv4(src), ipv4(target), data[header_length:]

def get__packets():
    conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))

    while True:
        raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65536)
        dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data = ethernet_frame(raw_data)


        # 8 for ipv4
        if eth_proto == 8:
            (version, header_length, ttl, proto, src_ip, target_ip, data) = ipv4_packet(data)
```

Why am I only getting private IPs? How can I get websites IPs? If it's not possible, how to get the http header from a TCP packet in order to get the url?

(I'm coding it on my raspberry pi 4 - Linux)

Comment: Are you using a local proxy for the web traffic? Then you won't see the actual website addresses in your packets.

Comment: If you're not going through a proxy, outgoing packets should have a private source address and public destination, incoming backets should be the opposite.

Comment: @Barmar Hi, no i'm not using any kind of proxy, i'm just connected to my raspberry pi (on which the packet sniffer is running) with SSH ( using PuTTY).

Comment: Is the RPi connected to a monitoring port on the switch? If not, it will only see packets to or from the RPi. And if the RPi isn't making connections to the Internet, it won't see any public addresses.

Comment: And if it's connected to a monitoring port, you need to put its Ethernet into promiscuous mode for it to receive packets that aren't sent to it.

Comment: @Barmar the RPi is only connected to wifi. Can I put its Ethernet into promiscuous on Ubuntu or do I have to get kali linux ?

Comment: You also need port mirroring on the WiFi AP. I'm not even sure if this is an option.

Comment: Ok I'll see thank you for your help.